# Remove main editor from wordpress edit page screen

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Anyone know of a way to remove the main editor from the page edit screen? And not just with css. I've added a few other meta boxes with the tinymce and they collide with the main one.

I have a class that removes other meta boxes from the edit screen, but I cant get rid of the main editor this way. I've tried to add 'divpostrich' and 'divpost' to the array in the class (but with no luck):

```
class removeMetas{
    public function __construct(){
        add_action('do_meta_boxes', array($this, 'removeMetaBoxes'), 10, 3);
    }

    public function removeMetaBoxes($type, $context, $post){
        /**
         * usages
         * remove_meta_box($id, $page, $context)
         * add_meta_box($id, $title, $callback, $page, $context = 'advanced', $priority = 'default')
         */
        $boxes = array( 'slugdiv', 'postexcerpt', 'passworddiv', 'categorydiv',
                        'tagsdiv', 'trackbacksdiv', 'commentstatusdiv', 'commentsdiv',
                        'authordiv', 'postcustom');

        foreach ($boxes as $box){
            foreach (array('link', 'post', 'page') as $page){
                foreach (array('normal', 'advanced', 'side') as $context){
                    remove_meta_box($box, $type, $context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$removeMetas = new removeMetas();
```

I have also tried removing the 'divpostrich' with jquery. But cant figure out where to put the js for it to work. When I remove the 'postdivrich' in the browser with firebug - my remaining tinymce fields work perfect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is the global `$_wp_post_type_features` array.

Below is a quick example of how it can be used

```
function reset_editor()
{
     global $_wp_post_type_features;

     $post_type="page";
     $feature = "editor";
     if ( !isset($_wp_post_type_features[$post_type]) )
     {

     }
     elseif ( isset($_wp_post_type_features[$post_type][$feature]) )
     unset($_wp_post_type_features[$post_type][$feature]);
}

add_action("init","reset_editor");
```

Comment: why the `if (!isset($_wp_post_type_features[$post_type])` line? Its not doing anything and the next line is checking anyway and will only unset if the associative array contains the required keys.

Comment: I agree, it is not needed, just need this: if ( isset($_wp_post_type_features[$post_type][$feature]) )
             unset($_wp_post_type_features[$post_type][$feature]);

Answer (score 34):

There is built in WP support for this so you don't have to fiddle directly with the globals and ensure forwards compatibility if they ever change how features are handled. The WP Core code does pretty much the exact same logic as @user622018 answer however

```
function remove_editor() {
  remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_editor');
```

Comment: Note: to do this selectively, for particular pages, you need to hook to something later. The global `$post` object isn't available at `admin_init`. I've used `admin_head` to disable the editor just for the home page.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code to your functions.

```
function remove_editor_init() {
if ( is_admin() ) {
    $post_id = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['post'])) $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', TRUE);
    if ($template_file == 'page-home.php') {
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_editor_init' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just disable the TinyMCE editor, leaving the HTML editor, as your meta boxes are colliding with it? :)

Comment: Nah, that will disable the TinyMCE's on my other meta boxes as well. And I want those :)

Answer (score 0):

To disable the editor you will need to edit your `wp-config.php` file and add this line to the top:

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
```

Comment: This constant prevents the theme/plugin editor from being used, but has no impact on the page editor screen.